# CodeWars sorting numbers and letters

Tags: javascript

I am currently doing a codewars problem, and I think I almost got it however, I ran across a problem when sorting index values with the same letter. link to problem is here. https://www.codewars.com/kata/5782dd86202c0e43410001f6

```js
function doMath(s) {
  let strSplit = s.split(' ');
  let clonedArr = strSplit.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < strSplit[i].length; j++) {
      let current = strSplit[i][j];
      if (isNaN(current)) {
        let letter = current;
        strSplit[i] = strSplit[i].replace(letter, '');
        strSplit[i] = letter + strSplit[i];
      }
    }
  }
  let sortedArr = strSplit.sort();
  console.log(sortedArr);
  //  ["b900", "y369", "z123", "z246", "z89"]


  let noLetterArr = sortedArr.map(x => {
    return x.slice(1);
  });

  let numberArr = noLetterArr.map(y => {
    return +y;
  })


  let firstEl = numberArr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < numberArr.length; i++) {
    if (numberArr.indexOf(numberArr[i]) % 4 == 1) {
      firstEl += numberArr[i];
    }
    if (numberArr.indexOf(numberArr[i]) % 4 == 2) {
      firstEl -= numberArr[i];
    }
    if (numberArr.indexOf(numberArr[i]) % 4 == 3) {
      firstEl *= numberArr[i];
    }


  }
  return firstEl;
}

console.log(doMath('24z6 1z23 y369 89z 900b'));
```

I would like to sort the `sortedArr` the ones with the same letter by how they first appeared in string. So since "z246" appeared first in the original string. I would like to have that before "1z23". I had a hard time creating a function for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you just wanting to sort by the first letter?.  If so if you sort by the first letter, Javascript these days uses a stable sort, so you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Could you post the link to the problem?

Comment: Regarding your question, not everyone is familiar with CodeWars, and some good answerers may not have time to go digging to find out the requirements. It would be better to frame your question in your own terms.

Answer (score 1):

```
var al = [];
function doMath(s) {
    var ar = s.split(" ");
    for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        for (let char of ar[i]) {
            let temp = char.match(/[a-z]/i);
            if (temp) {
                al[i] = char;
                ar[i] = ar[i].replace(char, '');
                ar[i] = char + ar[i];
            }
        }
    }
    al = al.sort();
    //New Sort Logic to pass above test case and others too
    var n = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < al.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < ar.length; j++) {
            if (ar[j].startsWith(al[i]) && !n.includes(ar[j])) {
                n.push(ar[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    var result = parseInt(n[0].substr(1)),
        count = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i < n.length; i++) {

        if (count == 1) {
            result = result + parseInt(n[i].substr(1));
            count++;
        } else if (count == 2) {
            result = result - parseInt(n[i].substr(1));
            count++;
        } else if (count == 3) {
            result = result * parseInt(n[i].substr(1));
            count++;
        } else if (count == 4) {
            result = result / parseInt(n[i].substr(1));
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    return Math.round(result);
}
```

Comment: I have created this code to pass all the test cases, hope the sort logic is clear to you according to the question asked.